# How to add lines using command line

Tags: html, shell, command-line, command

I have an HTML doc in which I want to insert automatically an image just after the body tag:

The html:

```
<body>
    <div class="indexHeader"><a href="allclasses-frame.html" target="packageFrame">All Classes</a>
</div>
....
```

And just after the `<body>` tag I want to add using command lines an image, and it will result like this:

```
<body>
    <img src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" />
    <div class="indexHeader"><a href="allclasses-frame.html" target="packageFrame">All Classes</a></div>
```

How can I achieve this in command lines?
Note: **I'm using Windows**.

These are my tries:
First try:

```
awk -v image='<img src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" />' '1; /<body>/ {print image}' overview-frame.html
```

As a result: 
The system cannot find the specified file.

Second try:

```
sed 's?<body>?<body>\n\t<img src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" />?g' overview-frame.html
```

As a result:
The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: Have you tried to achieve it? We would like to see your try. (anyway, check awk and sed)

Comment: Yes, but none of them drove me closer to the solution. That's why I didn't post my tries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular purpose, you can use `sed` that way:

```
sed 's?<body>?<body>\n\t<img src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" />?g' filename
```

where `filename` is the file containing html code. The previous line will print the updated file on screen, but it will not save the modification in the file: use `-i` option of `sed` to do this.

This solution is very specific to the problem you exposed, if you want a more complex modification, read `man sed` or google for sed examples.

Comment: Not working... It says:
sed 's? src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" / 0<i
mg 1>?g'
The system cannot find the specified file.
It can be same as above? The open and close tags?

Comment: Did you correctly replaced `filename` by the name of the file containing the html code ? It works on my machine.

Comment: I'm writing exactly the same line:

sed 's?<body>?<body>\n\t<img src="resources/logo_small.png" alt="My image" height="80" />?g' overview-frame.html

But it's not working...

Comment: Well, I don't understand why it's not working with your machine but working on mine... Sorry. Maybe we should compare versions of our OS/interpreter/sed...

Comment: Maybe different versions of Sed... Thanks anyway! Your answer drove me to the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I could finally make it work using this code:

```
sed -i "s#<body>#<body>\n\t<img src='resources/logo_small.png' alt='FacePhi Biometria' height='80' />#" filename
```